# Ads in small layout doesn't appear

Tags: xml, android-studio, admob, ads

I have many layout for my app, and in all of them the ads work just fine, except for the small layout and I have no clue of what might be the problem.
In every layout folder I made the **layout** file and the **fragment** (for each screen size).
I run the application on the device (large and extra large screen) and it works. But when I use the small screen device, it doesn't.

**layout XML file:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".java0"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:background="#ffff7e00">

    <!---->
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="nadsat.aplicacion.safrapp.lajerganadsat.java0$PlaceholderFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ad"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/adFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:name="nadsat.aplicacion.safrapp.lajerganadsat.java0$AdFragment"
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ad"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/duda"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:id="@+id/bDuda"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bOtras"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Otras aplicaciones"
        android:id="@+id/bOtras"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bLista"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bLista"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bLista"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/bLista"
        android:id="@+id/bLista"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(The fragment and layout codes are the same for each screen size.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost certainly because you have set a left/right padding for the RelativeLayout in your outer layout file.

Look at your logcat. It will tell you if it can't show the ad because it doesn't have enough size.

Comment: There will *definitely* be some AdMob related log in your logcat. Post it.

Comment: You still haven't posed any logcat. The answer will be in there.

Comment: I don't find that logcat thing anywhere

Comment: I found the logcat(UPDATE), but now, I try to change height and width but is still not working.

Comment: As I said - remove the left/right padding in your top level RelativeLayout.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much, sorry for troubling you haha. Thanks